# Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send via proxy

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

Error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

via : proxy
```

powershell version 4.0, the same request works with later version of powershell

Tried to invoke web request

```bsh
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer 7jNQ0nL"}
Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri https://api.line.me/v2/bot/user/all/richmenu  -Method Get  -Proxy proxy.xx.xxxnet.com:8080 -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials  -Headers $headers
```

but this is what happens:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri https://api.line.me/v2/bot/user/all/richmenu  -Method Ge ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: I tried to clean up the messy formatting but I had to guess in a couple of places. Please review.

Comment: Also, if there is a proxy, what kind of proxy exactly, and does things work if you take out the proxy?